# Unable to select and move a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I have recovered an open source project and I would like to move buttons and their size, but when I try to select a button individually it is the frame that contains all the buttons that is selected.

Do you know how to fix this problem?
[see screenshot thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpJ9w.png)

Thanks

Comment: It's probably a UserControl -- You forgot to mention what GUI platform you're referring to. All those VS tags don't mean much, you should replace them with some meaningful ones. You could also post the (partial) content of the designer's file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are a winform project or a WPF project.

As jimi said, from the screenshot it looks like you have a usercontrol selected. Unless you have its corresponding cs file in your project, it is difficult for you to modify the size and position of the controls directly.

You may need to use a decompiler to view the code of the corresponding control, and then reproduce and create a corresponding usercontrol or buttons yourself.

Download ILSpy 2022 in Manage Extensions of VS:

[image]

The dll file corresponding to Tools->ILSpy->File->Open. You can find out what the corresponding control code is.

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks... I tried ILSpy 2022 but couldn't find anything...

Yes I have a file named "FMain.cs" which corresponds to the interface where the User control is... when I display the code I don't know where the User control is

Comment: In the designer.cs in your screenshot, you should be able to find which dll it belongs to, find the corresponding dll and the corresponding control name, and you should be able to find it. I believe an open source project should not encrypt this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vt66.png Of course, what you need to know is that I use the default name here, and it may not be called usercontrol in your project. Try the next step, I will follow up if there is a problem. What's in "FMain.cs"?

Comment: Is there any update in this issue? @zollen123.